# How to prove the following equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $(A\cup B) \setminus A=B\setminus A$ is true for arbitrary sets $A$ and $B$.
So far I have: 
\begin{align}
&x \in (A\cup B) \setminus A\\ 
\implies &x \in A \text{ or } x \in B, \ x \notin A\\ 
\implies & x \in A\setminus A \text{ or } B \setminus A\\
&As \ A \setminus A = \emptyset,\\ 
\implies &x \in B\setminus A
\end{align}

However I'm not sure how to do the reverse of this proof, and if there's any steps that I have missed. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please show us that you have at least tried the problem before asking !

Comment: I couldn't get the texcommands to work but basically I have proven up to the point where i can say x is in A\A or x is in B\A. And since A\A is the empty, set, x is in B\A. However I;m not sure how to word this properly and then how to do the second part of the proof working backwards.

Comment: If what I edited was what you meant , then isn't the reverse direction almost out there ? $x \in B \setminus A \implies x \in A \cup B, x \notin A \implies x \in (A \cup B) \setminus A$

Comment: Yeah that's perfect thanks, I just didn't know how to include the empty set part in the reverse direction. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you only proved $(A\cup B)\backslash A\subset B\backslash A$, not the equality.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$$A\setminus B=A\cap B^c.$$

Comment: Notice that $\displaystyle A\backslash B$ looks different from $\displaystyle A\setminus B$. The latter is standard and I changed it in the article. ${}\qquad{}$